# Starting Ubuntu after first installation

Tags: wireless

I have just installed Ubuntu on a laptop.

I am trying to set up the WIFI but I am asked to supply a "root" password to get supervisor access.

When downloading I set up a username and password.

Searching the net I am pointed to "sudo" and "gksudo" to try to get administrative priviledges. I find out how to get these but trying to get them I find I need administrative privileges. Thus I am going round in a circle. I can't find anything (yet) that can point me in the right direction.

How should I proceed?

Comment: The password you supplied for username while installation is your root password

Comment: @cshubhamrao Write an answer :)

Answer (score -1):

If you absolutely need real root access and you don't know the password, try running in a shell

```
sudo su
```

It will ask for your password. This will be the password you use to log into the computer for your regular user. After you put your password in, type

```
passwd
```

This will ask for a new Unix password, and voila! You have changed (and now know) the root password!